# Why is my sed command failing when using variables?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

using bash, I'm trying to insert a variable for the date and search a log file for that date, then send the output to a file.  If I hardcode the date like this it works:

```
sed -n '/Nov 22, 2010/,$p' $file >$log_file
```

but if I do it like this it fails:

```
date="Nov 22, 2010"
sed -n '/$date/,$p' $file >$log_file
```

The error I get is: `sed: 1: "/Nov 22, 2010/,": expected context address`
Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://backreference.org/2009/12/09/using-shell-variables-in-sed/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In shell scripts, there is a difference between single and double quotes. Variables inside single quotes are *not* expanded (unlike those in double quotes), so you would need:

```
date="Nov 22, 2010"
sed -n "/$date/,\$p" $file >$log_file
```

The backslash escapes the dollar sign that should be taken literally by the shell and has a meaning to sed.

Comment: yeah, but then you've got to escape the one before p: ,\$p

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: Fixed that, saw your comment after

Comment: You can also mix your quotes, if it saves you escaping a lot of characters: `"/$date/"',$p'`