# Using variables with sed (UNIX)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am trying to read in a log file and create a new file with only the entries after the given date and time. For example I am looking for only after the time 07:00:00.000 in the below log:

```
2015-01-16 00:00:00.001 DATA
2015-01-16 07:05:00.121 DATA
2015-01-16 07:10:15:543 DATA
```

Would go to:

```
2015-01-16 07:05:00.121 DATA
2015-01-16 07:10:15:543 DATA
```

I can already get this to work with:

```
sed -n '/^2015-01-16 07/,$p' oglog.log > newlog.log
```

But when I try to add the date via a variable:

```
date=$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

I cannot get it to work. I know you need to get the shell to expand variable via either double or single quotes (https://askubuntu.com/questions/76808/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command), but with either of these methods it causes problems with `$p` in the replacement part of the sed command. How can I get the shell the expand one variable but not the other and use a command similar to below?

```
sed -n '/^$date/,$p' oglog.log > newlog.log
```

Comment: use double quotes in sed.

Comment: Right I have tried this method:
`result=$(sed -n "/^$testDate/,$p" logtest.log > newlogtest.log)`
returns: `sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unexpected ','` and
`result=$(sed -n '/^"$testDate"/,$p' logtest.log > newlogtest.log)`
returns an empty file.

Comment: Note that if the first event after 07:00:00.000 is at 08:00:00.000, nothing will be printed.  You might need to use `awk` which can do `>=` comparisons

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good to know! This log has 10's of entries every minute so I think it will be alright.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my sed command failing when using variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252280/why-is-my-sed-command-failing-when-using-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -n "/^$date/"',$p' oglog.log > newlog.log
```

You want the `$date` expanded by the shell, so that needs to be in double quotes.  You don't want the `$p` expanded by the shell, so that needs to be in single quotes.  You could also use a backslash to prevent the shell expanding that `$p`, but that quickly gets nasty if you have other meaningful backslashes in the regex:

```
sed -n "/^$date/,\$p" oglog.log > newlog.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
sed -n "/^$date/,\$p" oglog.log > newlog.log
```

variables are not expanded in single quotes.

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words